# d3.scaleBand not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Shouldn't it work with this library? `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js">`  I've tried all the libraries that I can find about this and none of them get rid of this error.  Any help would be great.

```
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([10, width]).padding(0.4),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 20]);
```

Comment: Have you tried `.paddingInner`?

Comment: Interesting, that got rid of that error, but now I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: 

d3.functor is not a function
    at Function.tip.offset (d3.tip.v0.6.3.js:113)
    at index.html:95
    at Object.<anonymous> (d3.v4.js:10999)
    at Dispatch.call (d3.v4.js:668)
    at XMLHttpRequest.respond (d3.v4.js:10924)

Comment: Ah, nevermind that, d3.v4 doesn't work with d3.tip apparently.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([10, width]).padding(0.4),
y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 20]);
```

Change .padding to .paddingInner like such

```
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([10, width]).paddingInner(0.4),
y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 20]);
```

Thanks to [Darren Sweeney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973552/darren-sweeney) for the answer.